# React redux-saga how to pass prop down to nested child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

Using

- `react 16.3.1`
- `redux`
- `react-redux`
- `redux-saga`

i wonder is there anyway to pass prop down to nested child without declare prop tag each time in each child ?
example
index.js

```
<Provide store={store}>
    <App />
</Prodiver>
```

App.js

```
....
render(){
    return (
        <div>
            ....
            <App1 dog={this.props.dog}/>
            ...
        </div>
    );
}
const mapStateToProps = () => .....
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

App1.js

```
export default function App1(props) {
    return <App2 dog={prop.dog}/>;
}
```

App2.js

```
export default function App2(props) {
    return (<div>{props.dog}</div>);
}
```

as u can see code above i have to pass prop tag in each child i has.is it possible to pass Props in App.js and get it in App2.js without passing from App1.js ?
Thank in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your component hierarchy is:
`App` -> `App1` -> `App2`

The `dog` prop of `App` comes from the redux store.

So you can also `connect` `App2` to grab `dog` from the store. This way, you skip the props passing through `App1`.

Comment: @Delapoute u mean that i have to use connect in App2 right ? `export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App2);` i thought connect only use in container

Comment: @Reaksmey You can have as many connections as you want. It allows for better declarative code as App2 will `connect` / take whatever it wants on it's own. Also it improves readability.